# how to convert nativeselect selected value vaadin

Tags: java, web, frameworks, vaadin

I have one native select like this :

```
 occupationSelect = new NativeSelect("Occupation:");
    occupationSelect.setRequired(true);
    occupationSelect.setRequiredError("Must Not be Empty");
    occupationSelect.setImmediate(true);
    occupationSelect.setWidth(COMMON_FIELD_WIDTH);
    occupationSelect.setNullSelectionItemId(0);
    occupationSelect.setItemCaption(0, "--Select");
    occupationSelect.addItem(1);
    occupationSelect.setItemCaption(1, "static");
```

in modal class Registration.java

```
    private OccupationBean occupationBean;
```

OccupationBean.java

```
    private Long occupationId;
    private String occupationName;
```

binding this field

```
  binderFieldGroupPersonalDetails.bind(occupationSelect,
            "occupationBean.occupationId");
```

I am getting this error :

Unable to convert value of type java.lang.Integer to model type class java.lang.Long. No converter is set and the types are not compatible.

there is no default convertor for IntegerToLong

how can I achieve this

Comment: occupationBean is a nested bean

Answer (score 3):

Simply use 0L instead of 0

```
occupationSelect.setNullSelectionItemId(0L);
occupationSelect.setItemCaption(0L, "--Select");
occupationSelect.addItem(1L);
occupationSelect.setItemCaption(1L, "static");
```